# Windows tool to set voice as password

Tags: windows, offline, security, login, voice-recognition

I am looking for a program to authenticate my Windows operating system based on my voice and the words I speak.

**Requirements:**

- Text password should be replaced with voice password
- Recognise voice modulations and authenticate users
- Offline verification of password should be done

Operating system: Windows platform.

Shareware will be accepted, but freeware is preferable.

**Additional information:**

The following software vendors were already tried, but sadly they were not for offline usage and it's all based on enterprise solutions apart from that, **it's speech recognition** not **voice recognition**:

(For those puzzled about the difference between voice and speech recognition, you could [read about it here](http://www.streetdirectory.com/travel_guide/139545/technology/key_differences_between_speech_recognition_and_voice_recognition.html).)

- [Agnitio](http://www.agnitio-corp.com/)
- [Armorvox](http://armorvox.com/)
- [Biovalidation](http://www.biovalidation.com/voice-identity-authentication.aspx)
- [Csid](http://www.csid.com/)
- [KYC Secure](http://www.kycsecure.com/)
- [Lexis Nexis Risk](http://www.lexisnexis.com/risk/)
- [Mistral (open source)](http://www.irit.fr/recherches/SAMOVA/pagemistral.html)
- [Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/)
- [Secure Reset](http://www.securereset.com/) (using Voxeo)
- [Sensory Speak](http://www.sensoryinc.com/)
- [SpeechPro](http://speechpro.com/)
- [Tradeharbor](http://www.tradeharbor.com/)
- [Voice Biometrics Group](http://www.voicebiogroup.com/)
- [Valid Soft](http://www.validsoft.com/)
- [Voice Trust](http://www.voice-trust.com/en/)
- [Voice Vault](http://www.voicevault.com/)

Comment: I did some research into this about a year ago and found that it wasn't a viable option for freeware/shareware users like yourself and I.  Hopefully someone finds something thought.  I'll be watching carefully ;)

Comment: @N.Soong for long time me too searching for it friend,updated links which i have tried before

Comment: I was just looking at that page you got those from myself!  From what I recall, it was possible to get software that you can login with speech recognition, but not *voice* recognition, meaning it was a pretty pointless password lol!  If you're interested in biometrics in general, check out Keylemon (https://www.keylemon.com/) I've found it's a little slow, but pretty accurate and cool!

Comment: yep,voice and speech recognition,the links were for **speech recognition** and not for **voice recognition** :(

Comment: If you get sick, your voice changes a bit in frequency. At that time if you try to access your computer via voice-recognition password. "Incorrect Password" will be shown.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with using voice recognition to protect your computer is that a voice is both too lax and too strict.

## Too lax:

It is actually REALLY easy, in this day and age, to record something spoken aloud. people can remotely activate webcam microphones and listen in on you, or they can "accidentally" leave their phone on your desk while at lunch, or they can even go the spy route and hide microphones in a variety of places, including ballpoints, your computer screen and even your overhead lights.

And even if you manage to avoid all that, text to speech technology has already progressed so far that you can generate a near-perfect copy of any voice. I just need to find a sample of you speaking and I can use that to generate a perfect or near-perfect rendition.

## Too strict:

now, suppose that you find a way to make it listen to your speech pattern and only your speech pattern. What if your speech pattern changes for some reason? Voices change quite a bit depending on what emotions you experience, how awake you are and even your health.

And even if you can keep your voice pattern the same, there's still the problem of background noise. any office has background noise, be it the cars outside, the other people in the room or even the white noise from devices in your room.

Also, what if someone else has to access your computer in an emergency? Something like "You got into an accident on the way to work and a coworker needs a file on your computer RIGHT NOW!". If that happens, it's hard to tell your coworker how to access your computer because they don't just have to enter something in your keyboard, but they actually have to mimic your speech pattern.

Finally, while speech recognition is relatively easy (disregarding accents), voice recognition is actually tricky, since you can have 2 people with VERY similar voice patterns, but who need to be authenticated separately. You also need to safeguard against an attacker that has hired a professional impersonation comedian or voice actor to mimic your voice.

The crucial flaw for voice recognition based security is that you need a system that is flexible enough to not lock you out if your voice is slightly different, while being strict enough to prevent compromise through a simple recording or simulation.

I have no doubt that there are already people working on managing these problems, but I don't foresee a usable and affordable voice recognition authentication system appearing in the next few years.

Comment: "text to speech technology has already progressed so far that you can generate a near-perfect copy of any voice" - wow! I'm looking for something like that for years and all I find is speaking >300 minutes of text for reproducing a voice, done by a professional company who would not even tell you the price on their website. What software do you use?

Comment: "needs a file on your computer RIGHT NOW!" - dismount the PC, connect the hard disk to another computer

Comment: "but who need to be authenticated separately" - if I read it correctly, he just wants to replace the password, not the user name. Of course this could still lead to issues, e.g. if they know each other and know that their voices are similar and know their user names

Comment: @ThomasWeller I remember reading about a US military project that managed to make a perfect voice replica of a high ranking general in a Dutch science magazine called Kijk a couple of years ago. I no longer have the magazine and they don't have an archive available online, but 5 year old miltech should be ending up on the pricey market right about now. In a few years, it'll probably be something you can do using an app.